# Unable to run hokuyo_node for Hokuyo URG-04LX

Tags: ros, laser, hokuyo-node, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm working on Surface Reconstruction from point cloud data and since in my lab there's an Hokuyo URG-04LX laser range finder, I would like to use it for building my data set. In order to get it working I followed this tutorial:

http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingTheHokuyoNode

In particular, I installed the ros node by running:

```
federico@HP-Compaq-8200:~$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-hokuyo-node
```

then, when I connect the laser to the PC, it gets associated to /dev/ttyUSB0 so I set the permissions for this port:

```
federico@HP-Compaq-8200:~$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 gen 12 15:47 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

after this, I set the parameters for hokuyo_node:

```
federico@HP-Compaq-8200:~$ rosparam get /hokuyo_node/calibrate_time
false
federico@HP-Compaq-8200:~$ rosparam get /hokuyo_node/port 
/dev/ttyUSB0
```

as explained in the tutorial, but when I run the ROS node it gives me this error:

```
federico@HP-Compaq-8200:~$ rosrun hokuyo_node hokuyo_node 
[ERROR] [1452610493.392974859]: Exception thrown while opening Hokuyo.
timeout reached (in hokuyo::laser::laserReadline) You may find further details at http://www.ros.org/wiki/hokuyo_node/Troubleshooting
```

I really have no idea of what could cause this problem, so any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223934/unable-to-run-hokuyo_node-for-hokuyo-urg-04lx/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2016-01-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Almost every URG-04LX-UG01 that I've seen enumerates as /dev/ttyACM0 (or ACM1, ACM2, etc). Are you absolutely certain that your port setting is correct? Do you have the serial version of the lidar instead of the USB version?

The error `timeout reached` suggests that there isn't any data coming in on that port, or something else is reading that data first. You should be able to check which programs have that port open with `sudo lsof | grep /dev/ttyUSB0`. If there are any other programs using that port, you should figure out why and disable them.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on 2016-01-13**:
Hi ahendrix! Thanks for your reply! My port setting was wrong, I was using only the serial connection. Thus, using also the usb connection solved the problem :)

**Comment by [ermanas](https://answers.ros.org/users/43196/ermanas/) on 2019-06-20**:
Hello, may I ask how did you solved the problem? I'm having the same issue. When I connect the device, system log says it's connected to the USB0 port. How did you figured the right port?